# OSB timeout before a response is received

Tags: timeout, osb

I have an OSB application that communicates with a web service. I'm sending requests with the test console. The result returned to the test console is empty. How can I increase the time while the application is waiting for a response?

Answer (score 2):

There are two parameters for connection. Connection Timeout & Read Timeout. Make sure, you are putting these value optimal.
(1) Connection Timeout - Timeout for making TCP connection to end-point. (usually 2 sec to 5 seconds.)
(2) Read Timeout - Timeout for getting & reading response from server/endpoint after successful TCP connection. (This should be based on SLA for interface contract.)

Thanks, Anil

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase business service response timeout, in OEPE (Eclipse).

Please select that Business Service -> HTTP Transport -> (Read Timeout or Connection Timeout).

Update it to appropriate value.

By default its value 0 (zero), means no timeout.